# \firstmark on \tableofcontents produces unexpected result

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr

So I am working on a rather small latex document and can't explaint the behavior of `\firstmark` on the `table of content` page.

Tell me if I'm wrong, but in my understanding `\firstmark` holds the first section heading on the current page. On the `\tableofcontents` page this should be `CONTENTS` I think.

In the `table of content` header this becomes `CONTENTSCONTENTS` and on the page itself it becomes just nothing. The `CONTENTS` on the left of the heading is irrelevant. I could remove this easily, but I just let it there to get the minimal source.

I got this small .tex source that reproduces this behavior:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[R]{\firstmark}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    foo

    \firstmark

    bar
\end{document}
```

And this is the pdf I get from this:
[image: The PDF I got after compiling the given .tex source]

As you can see in the heading on the upper right, there is `CONTENTSCONTENTS` instead of just a single `CONTENTS` and where you should see `CONTENTS` between `foo` and `bar`, there is absolutely nothing.

I also copied this source to [LaTeX Base](https://latexbase.com/), to exclude the possibility that this is an error on my computer.

Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the low-level `\firstmark` with latex. In latex the mark is split in two parts and you access the  left and right part with `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. Marks should be used only in the header and footer and not in the text body as they are reliable only when a page is shipped out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Leftmark: \leftmark, rightmark: \rightmark, firstmark: \firstmark}

\begin{document}
 \markboth{AAAA}{BBBB}

 some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I want to have the first section heading in the right header of the current page. Now do I have to mark every section with `\markright{theSectionHeading}`  and set `\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}`or how do i do this?

Comment: \section issues by default \markright in article cls (and if you want to change this, redefine \sectionmark)